# Android: Make an overlay match content height instead of expanding parent's height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />

        <!-- This is the element of interest. 
             View is actually a custom element, but for this example, View has same behavior -->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/MyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#A4D38D14" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which results in the following. Orange is the size of the View of interest. No-matter what I try, it seems I cannot get the View to not expand the parent.

[image: Bad image]

What I really want, is for the View to scale to the same height as the Image like this:

[image]

How can this be achieved? 
Note: I do not know the size of the Image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the code and you are good to go.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/MyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="#A4D38D14" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The key is to specify `android:layout_alignBottom` on the View and change the frame layout to relative layout

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you may also try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">



           <ImageView
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                   android:id="@+id/imageView"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />

           <!-- This is the element of interest.
                View is actually a custom element, but for this example, View has same behavior -->
           <View
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
                   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                   android:id="@+id/MyView"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:background="#A4D38D14" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am posting this because as far as I am concerned `ConstraintLayout` is designed to use a single layout for the entire design,

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a problem like you and figure out that the problem is generated for the `<View>` item. I fixed the problem by **replacing** the `<View>` with `<Linearlayout>`. Maybe `<View>` had a special characteristic that's why it is being overflown. My code snippet is -

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           <!-- This is the view intended to be the overlay-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_overlay"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```